# "Failed to load product definitions" error message appears while installing VS 15 preview 4

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am getting the Following error while trying to install VS 15 (not 2015) preview 4:

> Failed to load product definitions

From the official documentation [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/news/releasenotes/vs15-relnotes#knownissues), there is not much:

> Error message "Failed to load product definitions." may appear
>
> Issue:
>
> You may experience the following error message when starting the Visual Studio installer application: "Failed to load product definitions."
>
> Workaround:
>
> In most cases, clicking the Refresh button will workaround this issue and successfully load the product definitions.

Refresh button does nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Reinstalled Windows 10 =\ (Now it works)

Comment: I still have this error with current RTW release... I cannot apply latest updates, this is very annoing

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_Channels`